# Python - проверка попадания в интервал

Tags: python, функции, list

Помогите пож-та написать функцию для проверки попадания в интервалы, например:
Дан список `a = [10, 40, 100, 200, 1000]`.
Для каждого значения аргумента функция должна выдавать порядковый номер интервала, в который оно попадает (снизу - больше, сверху - меньше или равно), например:

```
20 - 1 (между 10 и 40),
130 - 3 (между 100 и 200),
1500 - 5 (больше 1000),
100 - 2 (больше 40 но не больше 100),
9 - 0 (меньше 10).
```

Т.е. нужен аналог экселевского ВПР с интервальным просмотром.

Comment: ну так что у вас не получается? сравнение? функция ваша где?

Answer (score 1):

Ну элементарно же. Просто идёте по списку и как только ваш элемент меньше или равен очередному элементу списка - индекс найден:

```
def find_index(x):
    a = [10, 40, 100, 200, 1000]
    for i, n in enumerate(a):
        if x <= n:
            return i
    return len(a)

assert find_index(20) == 1
assert find_index(130) == 3
assert find_index(1500) == 5
assert find_index(100) == 2
assert find_index(9) == 0
```

Comment: Ну или bisect...

Comment: @MBo Смотря сколько интервалов. Если их всегда мало, то смысла в двоичном поиске не будет. Но так то да, если их много, то имеет смысл оптимизировать. Если значения не очень большие, то можно и словарь прям сделать на каждое значение, ну кроме меньше минимума и больше максимума ))

Comment: Да, конечно....